# FormArray element getting removed incorrectly in angular reactive forms

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to remove an empty element from formArray and the code perfectly works fine when removing a just one instance. However if I try to store in array and then remove, it removes all the element irrepective of its empty. The storing of number into the array is commented below. Any idea whats the issue here with number array ?

```
if(this.readonly) {
  //const index = [];
  let index: number;
  this.accounts.controls.forEach((control, i) => {
   const result  =  Object.values(control['controls']).find((key: any) => {
     if(!key.value) {
         return key.value;
     }
     if(key.value?.value || key.value?.fieldMetaData) {
       return false;
     }
     return key.value != null ;
   });
   if(!result) {
     index = i;
   //index?.push(i);
   }
  });
  this.accounts.controls.splice(index);
  // for (var _i = 0; _i < index.length; _i++)
  // {
  //   this.accounts.controls.splice(_i);
  // };
}
```

Comment: You need use the method [removeAt](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray#removeAt) of FormArray, and [insert](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray#insert) **not** splice or push over "controls".